# Pre-fill marketo forms

Tags: marketo

What's best practice for pre-filling out a form when it's not built on top of a Marketo landing page.

Forms 2.0 doesn't seem to support reading from the cookie, and the Rest API requires you to already have their Marketo ID..

I'm thinking the only way to do this would be to pass the users values through an email, but that doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use this one :http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/  to get the ID of the customer by using `filterType=cookie`

2) Now that you have the ID, you can use this guide: http://developers.marketo.com/blog/external-page-prefill/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the REST API for some reason, you can embed a hidden iframe with a Marketo landing page and Marketo form that has the same fields enabled to prefill. Then you can use JS to get these values and post them into the parent frame's Marketo form.

Comment: If you use wordpress you can also use this free plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/genius-marketo-form-prefill/